# Neo4j: How to get additional nodes from nodes in a path?

Tags: neo4j

I have nodes in a chain, like this:

```
(n {height:100})
 |
(n)
 |
(n)
 |
(n)
 |
(n)
```

I can get these nodes with this cypher query:

```
MATCH chain=(start :n {height:100})-[:chain*4]->(end :n)
RETURN chain
```

---

However, each node in this chain also has a single node coming off it with a specific relationship, like this:

```
(n)-[:single]->(o)
 |
(n)-[:single]->(o)
 |
(n)-[:single]->(o)
 |
(n)-[:single]->(o)
 |
(n)-[:single]->(o)
```

I would like to return each `(n)`, as well as the `(o)` coming off it.

Is it possible to do this in one cypher query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem, though this is easier if we don't match on the path, but get all nodes in the chain (and the single node off of each) instead.

```
MATCH (start :n {height:100})-[rels:chain*0..4]->(chainlink :n)-[:single]->(o)
RETURN chainlink, o
ORDER BY SIZE(rels)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is simpler than the solution I found below.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems the use of `WITH(chain)` and `UNWIND` does the trick:

```
MATCH chain=(start :n {height:100})-[:chain*4]->(end :n)
WITH NODES(chain) AS nodes
UNWIND nodes as node
OPTIONAL MATCH (node)-[:single]->(o :o)
RETURN nodes, COLLECT(o) as os
```